# Extend partition to fill empty space after imaging

Tags: windows-7, imaging, clonezilla

We are using Clonezilla to make our computer images. Since we are deploying this image on many different hard drive sizes, we shrink the main partition to be lower than 80GB before we make the golden image.

Sometimes the tech forgets to enlarge the partition after the computer has been imaged by following the steps [here](http://www.petri.co.il/extending-the-system-partition-in-windows-7.htm).

How would one go about created a post-image script to enlarge partition 2 to fill the maximum space available that would run automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using **sysprep** as recommended by MS before you capture your image?  One of the sysprep options is to expand the drive.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715906.aspx

Comment: We are. This helps plenty. Cant see why we have overlooked this in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [RunOnce entry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346765.aspx) to the image (to be triggered on the first boot of the image), and script/use [Diskpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490893.aspx) to extend the volume.  This will require some testing and configuration on your part, but I've done something similar with a different Linux-based PC-imaging solution.